# how to do a loop of html textarea per line with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried this code to no avail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea name="" id="list" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit">
    <script>
        var string = document.getElementById('list');
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            var link = 'http://localhost/oke.php?list=' + string.value;
            oke(link);

        });
        async function oke(data) {
            var post = await fetch(data);
            var resp = await post.json();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

for example, the value of Textarea is as follows

```
tiger
rhino
elephant
wolf
```

and if possible I want after one of the lists has been processed, it will disappear from the Textarea.
thanks

Comment: do you want to split texts by new line??

Comment: yes, thats what i want

Comment: var ks = $('#keywords').val().split(/\r?\n/);

Comment: is thats for juery?

Comment: yes it is for jquery

Comment: The rest is not jQuery. just use `string.value.split(/\r?\n/);`

Comment: @MetropolisCZ Turning this into a stack snippet is pointless when url is unreachable. Don't edit old questions just to make them into snippets especially when the snippet is not runnable